# Copy local file remotely, execute and bring the output back

Tags: c#, remoting, powershell-remoting

Can someone help me with this problem?

I have got a set of executable files locally, and those need to be run remotely and the output returned from them. I've got the remote machine logon credentials. Could you let me know if there is a way to do this programmatically in C++, C#/powershell/WMI etc?

Comment: Your question is ambigue. Who runs these files? Someone from a remote computer or you need to upload them somewhere and execute from the remote machine? What kind of output these executables produces? (Files, console output)

Comment: @Pete, I tried Powershell remoting using Invoke-Command but this cannot copy files to remote machines.

Comment: @Steve, My program has to copy an exe/bat file to a remote machine, execute it and bring the results back to the local machine.

Comment: I think it's a pretty clear question. I don't think it should have been closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at using Both PSTools combined the the c# Process Class. PSTools allow you to fire processes remote machines.

An Example :-

** EDIT **

An example of running a batch file on a remote machine :-

```
// Create a New Process Object.
Process p = new Process();

//Assign the file you wish to execute.
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Utilities\\psexec.exe";

// We don't want a window creating for this task
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

// We don't want to use the operating system shell.                           
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

// Here we set the argument to fire on the remote machine that will launch the Batc File.
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\\\\" + RemoteMachineName + " C:\\YourBatFile.bat";

// Now to Start the Process.
p.Start();

// If you want to wait until the Process before moving on
p.WaitForExit();
```

This should give you the Idea to move forward with other tasks. It works for more than just opening files. You can use it to Insatll / Uninstall MsiInstaller products just like you can with WMI. If you want to Redirect the Output, you simply store it in a string object.

Comment: How do I copy files to remote machine using this?

Comment: Please see my update. This is a very quick and easy thing to do. I hope this helps.

Comment: Off the top of my head, If you want to copy files across to a remote machine you just have to use File.Copy("FileToCopy","Destionation"); You just add the full directory path in each string value. You should be able to fine that out quite easily on the net though.